# How to get image from the page and store in variable via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
img src="~/Images/Barcodes/MGRNNo.jpg" id="barCodeImage" width="150px" height="60"
```

I want to store the above image in variable via jQuery

like 
`var barcodeimage=$('#barCodeImage').image();`
and
I want to print it
like

```
applet.append64(barcodeimage);
applet.print();
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to change the image to base64 string?

Comment: .image() - It is not a function of jquery, I think you want to get the src ... var barcodeimage=$('#barCodeImage').attr('src');

Answer (score 0):

As I can see based on your example code I suspect that you want to have the base64 code of the image right?

Anyways, What you can do is get the outerHTML of the `<img>` object and encode that as a base64 string. In the end you can use the base64 string to decode it:

```js
// get object
var barcodeimage = $( "#test" )[ 0 ].outerHTML;
console.log(barcodeimage);

// Encode the String
var encodedString = btoa(barcodeimage);
console.log(encodedString); 

// Decode the String
var decodedString = atob(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/stackoverflow-logo-300.png" id="test"></img>
```

The btoa() method encodes a string in base-64. Use the atob() method to decode a base-64 encoded string.